# NO auto completion in EClipse IDE

Tags: ide, eclipse

I am new to salesforce and recently i have installed Eclipse IDE.

but somehow i dont know why ctrl + space is not working ..

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Silly question - but I assume you have installed the Force.com IDE plug-in>?

Comment: Which Plugins?

and thanks for your reply...As i said..M new to salesforce..if i wouldnt ask questions  then how will i learn

Comment: Auto-completion looks like it still isn't there in the Force.com IDE Eclipse tooling (that you need to install in addition to the core Eclipse Java platform - see [Force.com IDE Installation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation)) - see https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues/20. Most people who have used both the Eclipse tooling and [MavensMate](http://mavensmate.com/) would recommend MavensMate; autocompletion works in MavensMate.

Comment: I would go with Mavensmate then..But isnt there any pluging availabe for eclipse???

Comment: Yes there is an Eclipse plugin (see link in my previous comment). So if you have a strong reason to use Eclipse go with that, but auto-completion won't be available.

Comment: i came accross a plugin "Apex Editor LS" ..does it work..and how can i test it in my eclipse

Comment: There is an install button here https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/apex-editor-ls.

Comment: Thank you i just installed it after writing the comment..I just wanted to know ..after installing this will i get the method name after hitting "Dot (.)" in apex classes or Ctrl + space will work?

Comment: Can someone clarify my query?

Comment: No, you won't get the method name after typing a dot.

Comment: Then whats the use of this plugin?

Comment: see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/79532/2602 for latest